# Particular Ehrenpreis factorization for covariance function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fourier-transform, convolution

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth compactly supported covariance function of a stationary random fields (hence positive definite).

Is there a compactly supported function $g:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g\ast g=f$ ?

Using Fourier transform and Bochner's theorem, this question is equivalent to the construction of a entire square root for entire function of exponential type that are positive and fast decaying on the real line.

Comment: And how do you expect to get an entire square root when the Fourier transform has simple complex zeroes (which isn't hard to arrange: take any positive and fast decaying on the line entire function of exponential type and multiply it by $z^2+\mu^2$ with some real $\mu$ such that $i\mu$ is not a zero of the original function)?

Comment: Very interesting, I did not think about multiplication by such function to obtain simple zeroes. So indeed, it is not always possible. I just need to make this assumption then. I wonder if it says something interesting about the covariances functions that cannot be root squared that way.